# Problem with loading hggit extension in TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, hg-git

I'm trying to get the hggit extension to work under Windows 7 (64bit) using TortoiseHG (2.1.2). I followed the official setup instructions, i.e. cloning the hg-git repository and adding the "hggit = ..." line to the extensions section in my mercurial.ini file.

However the extension doesn't seem to be loaded. When trying to clone a repository I get the following error :

```
abort: repository git://... not found!
```

running

```
hg help hggit
```

results in

```
hg: unknown command 'hggit'
```

I also don't get any errors at all, no matter what I put in the extensions section of the mercurial.ini file.

Any ideas on what the problem might be ? Are there any log files at all that show me whether there are problems loading the extensions ?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, and in my case I forgot to specify the `[extensions]` line in the INI file.

***Not*** working:

```
[ui]
username = My name <my@emailaddress.com>
hgsubversion=D:\Repotools\hg-svn\hgsubversion
hggit=D:\Repotools\hg-git\hggit
```

**Working:**

```
[ui]
username = My name <my@emailaddress.com>

[extensions]
hgsubversion=D:\Repotools\hg-svn\hgsubversion
hggit=D:\Repotools\hg-git\hggit
```

When you run the command `hg help hggit` it will report if the directory path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should include what you have after `hggit =`

It should be pointing to the hggit subdirectory in the directory you cloned the repository into.

e.g. `hggit=C:\hg-extensions\hg-git\hggit`

Comment: yes that's exactly what it says. hggit = C:\tools\hg-git\hggit . I also tried slashes instead of backslashes, didn't change anything either. I also can put any directory and don't get an error messages which makes me believe that the extension section is not even considered when running hg.exe ...